# Unsupported combination of input and output array formats in function cv::reduce

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation

I am trying to run a code of line segmentation that I found on GitHub. When the program reaches this line of code:

```
def invert(im):
    im = abs(255 - im)
    im = im / 255

    return im


def enhance(im):
    kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
    im = cv2.erode(im, kernel, iterations=1)
    kernel = np.ones((15, 15), np.uint8)
    im = cv2.dilate(im, kernel, iterations=1)
    return im


im = cv2.imread(filename, 0)
imbw = sauvola.binarize(im, [20, 20], 128, 0.3)
im = invert(im)
im = enhance(im)
hist = cv2.reduce(im, 1, cv2.REDUCE_SUM, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
```

I get this error:

> error: OpenCV(3.4.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix_operations.cpp:1111: error: (-210) Unsupported combination of input and output array formats in function cv::reduce

I have tried all `dtype` values available for cv2.reduce() function. I have also tried to change the datatype of image using numpy. But, still I am getting the same error.

Full Code: https://github.com/smeucci/LineSegm/blob/master/python/linesegm/lib/linelocalization.py#L41

Comment: Is that `imbw = sauvola.binarize(im, [20, 20], 128, 0.3)` realy needed in your example? I don't have the implementation (most probably it's in your repo) but I think it is not need as you do not use `imbw`. Wrote my answer as there is no that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

`imread()` returns `uchar` data, but you process it as if you get floats.

```
im = im / 255
```

For example this line of code will make all pixels equal zero if you will apply it *uchar OpenCV matrix*.

Convert your `im` pixel format to floats after you read the image. This code works for me:

```
im = cv2.imread("im.jpg", 0)
im = np.float32(im)
im = invert(im)
im = enhance(im)
hist = cv2.reduce(im, 1, cv2.REDUCE_SUM, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
```